# When is the NULL counted in the following SQL query

Tags: sql, select, count, null, where-clause

I came across two queries and thought that the meaning of the two queries would lead to the same answers. However, it seems that the answers would be wrong if due to NULL.. but I'm not sure exactly how the two results would come out differently.

**Query A**

```
select count(*)
from person
where person.height < 156 or person.height => 156;
```

and

**Query B**

```
select count(*)
from person;
```

I know that select count(*) means to print while also counting the NULLs. However, I'm not sure if there would be any different when the where condition is also given.

Comment: The first query is filtering the rows being counted.  The second is not.  Why would you think that they would return similar results?

Comment: `count(*)` counts rows. `count(col)` counts non-null values.

Comment: @GordonLinoff well.. since the ```where``` condition is basically containing all of the numbers, I thought it wouldn't really matter whether the ```where``` is there or not.. So I thought that both would show the same result.. is that not right?

Comment: @Learner_15 You do realise the where condition is querying two different columns right?

Comment: @GarethD oh god... that was a mistake... I will change it immediately...

Comment: Even though your where condition contains all the numbers, it doesn't contain any logic for `NULL`, so any rows with a `NULL` age won't be counted, whereas they will in the second query. To make your two queries comparable, change the second one to `SELECT COUNT(age) FROM Person`, or change your first where clause to `where person.height < 156 OR person.Height >= 156 OR person.Height IS NULL` (although this is a pointless clause)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the `person.height` column has nulls in it, then those rows will not be counted by your first query.

This is because null is a flag not a value, and therefore it cannot return true for any value-comparison operator.  It is thus neither greater than, nor less than, nor equal to anything (including another null).  The only test a bare null can return TRUE for is one like `person.height IS NULL`.